# How to load linked entities with IdentityUser and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently writing a small test application to understand how IdentityUser works.

I've created a **MyUser** class that inherits from IdentityUser. The only additional property on my custom user class is a collection of my **Book** class.

I've created methods on the controller that successfully store new users to the database and associated Books. The problem is when I try to retrieve a user, the Books collection for that user is not populated  - it's always null.

When I check the database I can see that a Book is stored in the database with an associated User ID however I can't seem to retrieve this collection.

Here is what I have so far:

**Book.cs:**

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Isbn { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

**MyUser.cs:**

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public IList<Book> Books { get; set; }  
}
```

**MyAppContext.cs:**

```
public class MyAppContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser>
{
    public MyAppContext() : base("MyApp")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

**AuthRepository:**

```
public class AuthRepository : IDisposable
{
    private MyAppContext _ctx;

    private UserManager<MyUser> _userManager;

    public AuthRepository()
    {
        _ctx = new MyAppContext();
        _userManager = new UserManager<MyUser>(new UserStore<MyUser>(_ctx));
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUser(RegistrationModel userModel)
    {
        MyUser user = new MyUser();
        user.UserName = userModel.UserName;

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> UpdateUser(MyUser userModel)
    {
        var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(userModel);

        return result;
    }

    public async Task<MyUser> FindUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

        return user;
    }

    public async Task<MyUser> GetUser(string userName)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

        return user;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ctx.Dispose();
        _userManager.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I figured maybe within the GetUser() method I could manually retrieve all books from the Book table with _ctx.Books.Where(b => b.MyUser_id == user.Id) however intellisense isn't even giving me the MyUser_Id property on the Books table.

I'm not really sure how to go about this. All I want to do is load all the associated books for a user automatically but I'm not sure how to do this. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Add UserId to your Book class add Foreign key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class for Book doesn't include user information for the foreign key reference.  Try adding

```
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public MyUser User { get; set; }
```

to the Book class definition.

When you get the users with the query

```
_ctx.Users.Include(u=> u.Books)
```

The books for each user should be included.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I just wonder if there's any way to populate this collection automatically when I retrieve the user? Or do I always have to manually populate as you've mentioned?

Comment: When you include the child entity its eager loading. you can mark the `Books` list as `virtual` for lazy loading. So whenever you access it the framework should get the data for you.

Comment: One other question: Your example works if I'm using my dbcontext to retrieve the users, but what if I'm accessing the user with the UserManager class as in my code above? How do I populate my books from there?

Comment: You can use that entity till its in the context. Once it gets out of the context you cannot access the Navigation properties to load data. So if your manager is instantiated with `using(var ctx = MyContext()){ You can access the navigation properties here....} After this you cannot`

Comment: Depending on the version of EF, you should probably make sure that the UserManager is disposing of the context when it is finished.  I think later versions don't require disposal, although most examples still show using contexts in a using clause.